# How to pass checked images in fragments

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment, bundle

i have listView, and there are checkbox, imageView, TextView. I wanna pass that images, that was checked in listView. I know that's doing with bundle, but how to do the checkbox part? I have checkbox, but i don't know how to initialize it.

Here's the adapter part.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyAdapter> {

String names[];
int flags[];
Context mContext;


public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] languageNames, int[] countryFlags) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_items);

    this.names = languageNames;
    this.flags = countryFlags;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_items, parent, false);
        mViewHolder.mFlag = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mViewHolder.mLanguage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);

    } else {
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    mViewHolder.mFlag.setImageResource(flags[position]);
    mViewHolder.mLanguage.setText(names[position]);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView mFlag;
    TextView mLanguage;
}}
```

You see there's only an image and textview. How to add checkbox to there?

Here's the listView part.

```
public class FragmentLanguage extends Fragment {

View mainView;
ListView listView;

Context mContext;

Button next;
MyAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Integer> mItems = new ArrayList<>();

int[] images = {R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download,
        R.drawable.download};

String[] languages = {"Armenian", "Russian", "US English", "Portugal",
        "Spanish", "Georgian", "French", "Italian"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
    listView = mainView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), languages, images);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    next = mainView.findViewById(R.id.next);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    return mainView;
}}
```

1)How to add the checkbox part? 2) How to send images from this fragment to another fragment with bundle?  Thanks. I'll write the bundle part here

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Comment: can't you just pass some sort of image `ID` to your fragments? this way you wont spend resources serializing and de-serializing heavy images ...

Answer (score 0):

OPTION 1:

make a list of Int `val listOfSelectedImages = arrayListOf()`

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener {

            if (checkBox.isChecked) {
                //when checked add image(example R.id.image1) to list
            } else {
                //remove from the list
            }

        }
```

from one fragment to another:

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      val mFragment2 = Fragment2()
      val bundle = Bundle()
      bundle.putParcelableArrayList(KEY, listOfSelectedImages)
      mFragment2.arguments = bundle
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment2)
            .commit()
     }
  });
```

in fragment 2 go `val list = getArguments.getParcelableArrayList(KEY)`

Comment: There's no intents. This is fragment.

Comment: No man, there's no Intent in fragment. Fragment is not activity. How i can do startActivity()?

Comment: I think you want to do this @HaykMkrtchyan

Comment: This would help i guess.